# Do open source copyrights/licences expire?

Tags: open-source

This is a purely hypothetical question, but current copyright in the U.S. is life + 70 (I think).

Some open source licences require derivative works to also be open source.

My question is, are programmers no longer required to open source the derivative code if the license expires?
How about in other countries where the copyright term may be shorter?

Comment: Interesting question.  I wonder how one would determine when the 70 years (or whatever the time frame is) starts.  If parts of the code were edited at different times, how is that determined?  OTOH... how much of today's code will still be useful in 70 years :)

Comment: It's your latter point that makes this question totally hypothetical. Just trying to appease my curiosity ;-)

And repositories can usually keep track of when the code was added.

Comment: I'll add that, while the question was "hypothetical" (because the timeframe AT THIS TIME is too much long compared to the life of a person), with shorter copyright it would be much more interesting. It's surely an interesting question about copyright and licenses (like there are many, for example tagged lincensing, legal...)

Comment: Now... As written in the GPL (I'll use it as an example) you use it INSTEAD of the meager rights given to you by the copyright laws. Clearly if the copyright expires then you can use the rights given to you by the PD instead of the license. Your derivative sw could be legal in some countries (expired copyr. of the base sw) and illegal in other. The expiration will be gradual. The GCC 0.9 will go PD before GCC 1.0, and 2.0 will go PD after that. I use GCC becasue its copyr is attributed to a foundation.

Comment: I don't get it: why is this closed in stead of moved to http://programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 3):

Copyright, in theory, expires. At that time the work, if not renewed or updated, would fall into the public domain.

However:

1. The Mickey Mouse copyright extensions means that every time a key work would enter the public domain, copyright terms are extended.
2. Software from as little as 10 years ago in general is not relevant - things move to fast.

Comment: I would mark this correct, but I would still like an answer to the second part of the question regarding other countries.

Comment: In theory?? gpl 3 outright says so: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/5358

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer (IANAL) but my understanding is that copyright is completely unrelated to open source licensing. Under US law, the author of a literary or other creative work automatically has copyright protection of their work.  No declarations or registrations are required. That copyright may expire some period of time after the author of the work is deceased. I'm not clear on the details, and the fact that the "Micky Mouse" copyright extensions keep changing that limit doesn't help clarity.

Open source licensing is not a right, it is a license that specifies the terms and conditions under which the source code may be used.  The author decides what license terms to release the source code under, and the licensees (consumers of that source code) are held to that license. If the author's code is based upon a prior work, the author's license term options may be restricted by the license of the prior work.

I'm not aware of any expiration date associated with licenses.  They are essentially contracts, so unless the contract/license explicitly states an expiration scenario, the license terms are in force forever.

Comment: But copyright does expire.  When it does, don't the works fall into the public domain?  At that point, who has the right to sue if a license is violated?  (I am also not a lawyer, nor do I play one on TV.)

Comment: If that's the case, why don't the movie/music industries use licences?

Comment: Sure, copyright expires.  But that's not the same as the license terms of use if the material was released exclusively under a license.

Comment: @Lazy: The movie/music industry does use licenses, aggressively.  Movie theaters are licensees of movie film prints. Radio broadcasters are licensees of music. Even artists who perform a cover/rendition of someone else's music are usually licensees of the original tune. When one of these entities makes a copy of the licensed work against the terms of the license, they get hauled off to court pretty quick for violating contract.  Copyright comes into play with people who have not agreed to a license for the material, such as a moviegoer recording a screening of a film in a theater.

Comment: And when the copyright expires, anyone can use the software, which renders the license useless at that point.  I don't see how a license can be enforceable after the copyright expires.

Comment: From the GPL v3: 2. Basic Permissions: All rights granted under this License are granted for the term of *copyright* on the Program, and are irrevocable provided the stated conditions are met. ... This License acknowledges your rights of fair use or other equivalent, as provided by *copyright* law.  [My emphasis]

Comment: Do movie licenses, such as the FBI warning at the beginning of a movie, not expire too?